# How to open image URL with application

Tags: images, url

Is there a way to modify the way an image URL is opened within a browser?  For example, say I wish to open all files with a JPEG extension in IrfanView instead of having it open in a new browser window.  Would this be possible?

Comment: You mean the image URL embedded **within** a webpage ?

Comment: @Sathya - Yes, the URL is embedded within the web page.

Comment: Brian, you're interested in how a browser behaves when you click on a **link to an image** or when you enter the **address of an image** in the address box, right? Sathya may be concerned you want a browser to do something special for images that are part of a web page, like the Super User logo at the top of this page -- if it were a JPEG.

Comment: What browser? (Out of the browsers I have installed, Opera has settings to do what you want, but Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Chrome don't have any obvious way to do it.)

Comment: @Bavi_H - Yes, you're correct.  I'm guessing our users will mostly be using IE or Firefox but Chrome support would be nice as well.  I doubt many will be using Opera.  After searching on Google for about an hour, it would appear that this is either impossible or extremely hard to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given here [How can I download the .mp3 file from Dropbox?](https://superuser.com/questions/198107/how-can-i-download-the-mp3-file-from-dropbox) to my question may be what you need.

Regards,

Comment: Yeah, except this only works for certain file types and JPEG isn't one of them.